# How to train a linear SVM with H2O

Tags: svm, h2o

The [H2OSupportVectorMachineEstimator](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/modeling.html) in H2O seems to only support "gaussian" as the value of the kernel_type parameter. Is there a way to train a linear SVM with H2O?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, based on the documentation (https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/svm.html) currently there is no way to train linear SVM on H2O. Within linear models, I think it only has GLM (https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glm.html).